# Python - reshape, pivot, unstack - multiindex

Tags: pandas, pivot, reshape

I have a dataframe below that I am trying to reshape. I've looked up how to do it, but am getting back multiple answers and when trying to implement getting errors as having duplicate index, or I'll get just 1 wide row dataframe. The options that I have been trying are unstack, pivot, and ravel. What would be the best and easiest way to reshape without iterating rows, which I know I could work out, but I also know there is a better way.

For sake of clarity, I provided a screen shot of an example of what I have, and what I'm trying to do:

Here's what I have (but with thousands of rows)

[image]

I'm trying to move rows underneith that have same Customer, Week, and Type to be on 1 single Row:

[image]

To look something like this:

[image]

EDIT: As asked below, just a a quick sample of the data set. I should have provided from the start.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Customer': ['Store_A']*12,
 'Class': ['1A','1A','2B','2B','3C','3C']*2,
 'Week':['08/19/2018','08/26/2018']*6, 
 'Type':['Food']*6 + ['Beverage']*6, 
 'Value': [None,None,1,1.5,1.1,1.2,None,None,0.96,0.70,0.96,0.96]}

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Comment: Can you create sample data in text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid duplicated columns names in pandas, so I recommended add counter for it:

```
g = test_df.groupby(['Customer','Week', 'Type']).cumcount().astype(str)

df = test_df.set_index(['Customer','Week', 'Type', g]).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)

df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  Customer        Week      Type Class_0  Value_0 Class_1  Value_1 Class_2  \
0  Store_A  08/19/2018  Beverage      1A      NaN      2B     0.96      3C   
1  Store_A  08/19/2018      Food      1A      NaN      2B     1.00      3C   
2  Store_A  08/26/2018  Beverage      1A      NaN      2B     0.70      3C   
3  Store_A  08/26/2018      Food      1A      NaN      2B     1.50      3C   

   Value_2  
0     0.96  
1     1.10  
2     0.96  
3     1.20
```